# Multiple Event Handlers in vue.js 1.0

Tags: javascript, event-handling, vue.js, eventhandler

Vue.js prior to 1.0 you could call multiple event handles in this manner:

```
<input type="text" v-on="
   keyup: onKeyUp,
   blur: onBlur
">
```

Now with the release of 1.0 the new syntax is as follows:

```
<input type="text" 
   v-on:keyup="onKeyUp" 
   v-on:blur="onBlur
">
```

I was hoping to find a way around calling v-on twice.  Can't seem to find any documentation on multiple event handlers for vue.js 1.0+

Comment: I believe the the first example technically does call v-on twice as it is parsed; but what reason do you need to only have v-on occur only once on your element?

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar Clean code.  Fewer characters.  It's not a functional problem, just an interest in minimizing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to minimize the amount of typing, you could use the new @event syntax introduced with 1.0:

```
<input type="text"
  @keyup="onKeyUp" 
  @blur="onBlur"
>
```

See the [vue.js documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/events.html) for more info.

Other than that, I don't think what you're asking for is possible with 1.0.